# Android BLE, Can't connect to device

Tags: android, bluetooth, btle

I'm making an application which has to talk to a BLE devices on Android.

I am running into issues establishing the connection to the BLE device.

**Case 1) Scan:**
During a scan after a device has been discovered and reported via

```
BluetoothLEScanCallback.onScanResult(...)
```

I am attempting the connect via:

```
result.getDevice().connectGatt(...)
```

Problem is on some devices I test this (namely HTC One M8 running Android 5.0.1 and HTC Desire 516 running Android 4.3) the connection process seems to fail, i.e. the callback

```
BluetoothGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange(....)
```

is simply not called most of the time. 
Now this is not a consistent behavior, sometimes it is sometimes it is not.

The second problem is that often if the connection is established 
the

```
BluetoothGatt.discoverServices()
```

call fails, i.e. the 
    BluetoothGattCallback.onServicesDiscovered(...)
is also not called. I tried retrying the call a couple of times spaced by X number of milliseconds but it seems to consistently fail regardless of the number of attempts or spacing between them.

**Case 2** Listening

The pretty much same thing happens when I attempt to simply "listen" for a device, again calling

```
BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothManager.getAdapter().getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
device.connectGatt(...)
```

results often in the same situation.

In both cases I am having issue with Android most of the time, I have a Nexus 5 device on which that same code seems to work for the most part (sometimes the BT stack seems to fail to do its job)
A bit more disturbing that the iOS application we have has none of these problems.

Has anyone encountered these issues? 
Any ideas how to address them?

Comment: Are you testing the boolean result of BluetoothGatt.discoverServices()?

Comment: Yes, I am checking it, and I have a retry policy, in case the BTLE is "busy" and does not wish to accept the call.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
 We did "solve" this one. Just in case somebody stumbles on such situation, the issue in my case is that ymmv a lot from device to device or even from connection to connection.
Sometimes the process happens in a second or so other times it takes 5, in my tests it can climb up to like 15 on the devices I test with. 
As for why this is I can't tell.

Comment: When you say you "solved" it, do you just mean you're waiting longer and eventually it connects? I'm seeing the same thing with an app that has hundreds of users but doesn't work properly on the HTC M8 and I'm waiting 30 seconds and still nothing.

Comment: Not really. It was a long time ago but the logic ended up being not as straightforward as simply waiting. One of the workarounds I used (saw it in the google bug tracker) was adding a delay between the time when the connection got established and the call to "discover services" basically any call I attempted without that delay (around a second) broke the connection. It would really help if you have a tool to explore the device state. I also ended up having "forced" retries if I detect such situation, basically wait a couple of seconds for the device to re-initialize and try again.

Comment: Also space out the commands, issueing them back to back proved to be problematic. And always mind the sequencing.

Comment: Ahh. I can't even get a connection to establish. Even the Nordic Master Control Panel app can't connect on the M8 with Android 6.